# Create triggers with RAISE

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm trying to limit a table to only one record and disable all attempt to add more.
I have created this trigger:   `CREATE TRIGGER abort_insert_to_my_tbl BEFORE INSERT ON my_tbl
BEGIN
 RAISE(ABORT,"You can't add records to my_tbl")
END;`

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: near line 3080: near "RAISE": syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) shows, RAISE is a function, not a statement, so it cannot be used directly in the trigger body.

To use a function in a statement, use, for example, a SELECT statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER abort_insert_to_my_tbl
BEFORE INSERT ON my_tbl
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'You can''t add records to my_tbl');
END;
```